# How to find a decent taxi company in Chicago?

Tags: taxis, chicago

I looked up taxi companies on Yelp, and all of them have 1-star reviews. Called a few and said "I'm going to be in Chicago tomorrow and need a ride to O'Hare" and they say either (a) "just call us 5 minutes before" (an impossible level of service), or (b) "give us 3-4 hours, about, maybe".

I'd think getting a cab from one part of Chicago to O'Hare would be pretty simple, but...

How might one find a decent taxi in Chicago?

Comment: Is a street hail not an option? Where specifically in Chicago do you need to get a cab *from*?

Comment: I think that what you assume to be "impossible level of service" might just be what is simply "normal" in some places. I think you should state what you want you actually need to be done, instead of asking for us to find out what is acceptable for you.

Comment: Unfortunately I'll be a few blocks off S. Cicero - not sure there are taxis going by there.

Comment: The terrible service of taxis is one big factor that led to the popularity of Uber. Consider not trying to find a taxi at all and getting Uber instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have had this problem in other US cities (and, to be fair, other countries/cities before). I think many taxi companies are not that interested in taking advance bookings - either they figure there's a good chance you won't turn up, or they just don't manage their taxis that way.

In either case, in US cities, when booking something like this a day or two in advance, I tend to use something like a limo/black car service instead - which isn't as expensive as you might be imagining (in other words, can be price competitive with a taxi). I tend to use an aggregator - something like [limos.com](http://www.limos.com), which searches several services. There are lots of alternatives, though.

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked for a taxi and I may have missed your reasoning behind it.

have you considered the L? I've taken it several times and it goes to more places than you think.

[Pink line station at s Cicero](http://www.transitchicago.com/travel_information/station.aspx?StopId=39).

Answer (score 0):

At ORD, there is a taxi stand right outside the terminals. You won't have to wait long, if at all. They're all generally fine, if no-frills. For something nicer, schedule a limo in advance.

Comment: If he was actually at ORD that bit about taxis might be worthwhile advice

Comment: The question is asking how to get a taxi *to* O'Hare....